# Does reading a GCP Cloud Storage nearline / coldline object's metadata incurs the access charge?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Google's Cloud Storage offers two per object storage classes that are associated with a lower storage price at the trade off of a slightly reduced availability, a minimum storage duration and a per access fee. Those are the nearline and coldline storage classes. (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes).

I was unable to find in the docs any indication on whether reading a nearline / coldline object's metadata only (without reading the object itself) is considered an "access" which is associated with the per access fee.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, meta-data access does count as "Data retrieval" for the purpose of Nearline and Coldline storage. The documentation you linked to is indeed unclear on that matter and should be updated with that information soon.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation now does a better job at laying out the pricing for different types of operations based on storage class. You can find the table here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing